# bash taking too long to respond

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash

Recently I have installed some large packages like ROS Indigo and like many other applications and since then my Ubuntu 14.04 bash is taking too long to respond like 8-10 sec, I really need help in speeding up the shell load time. Anyone, thanks in advance. I tried updating `bashrc` with `set -x` and `set +x`, but nada.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to be your problem. But there are missing info.
- Check your logs (syslog, dmesg, /var/log/messages, journatctl -xe, whatever) to see if you have some problems system-wide.
- Check you .profile, .bashrc, /etc/profile[.d] and /etc/bash.bashrc to see what those load with bash.
- Try ksh or any other to see if the problem is more generic than bash.
  -- If it is only bash, you better start with clean profile and bashrc for checking.

Comment: okay so what elements to check in `bashrc`

Comment: Send you .bashrc and /etc/bash.bashrc along.

Comment: Also, you enable -x , I suppose first thing on .bashrc. 
What does it show? Can you post the output of that, too?